# How do I prevent terminal from hanging after running a tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a tkinter program but anytime I run the program, the terminal hangs. Is there a way I can prevent the terminal from hanging when the tkinter program is running? Thanks in advance

```
PS C:\Users\DANIEL\Desktop\exp\fcnvmb\results> & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/DANIEL/Desktop/exp/fcnvmb/GUI.py
***************** Loading Testing DataSet *****************

*******************************************
            START TESTING
*******************************************
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\_reduction.py:42: UserWarning: size_average and reduce args will be deprecated, please use reduction='mean' instead.
  warnings.warn(warning.format(ret))
The testing psnr: 15.81, SSIM: 0.5168 
Testing complete in  0m 2s
```

Comment: That is exactly how most any command you run from the terminal would work - why would you expect your program to behave any differently?  You could try running it with `start` (followed by whatever command you're currently using), to detach it from the terminal.

Comment: @jasonharper, thanks for the comment. But I actually don't get what you mean. I run the Tkinter program using VS code and the terminal in VS code hangs. What you mean by "running with start".